# How to disable authorization for single path within @Controller using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

It is possible to disable authorization for specific paths by configuring `HttpSecurity`:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
      ...
      .antMatchers("/some/open/resources/**")
      .permitAll();
}
```

Is it also possible to do the same thing on the Spring `@Controller` level? Preferably by some annotation, like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/open/resources/")
@NoAuthorization
public void get() {
    // return something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but you can do something like this :

```
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/viewFingerprints").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

And you can access only `/home` and `/viewFingerprints`, 
the rest will be blocked.